# SQL 2000 DB problem : I/O error (torn page) detected during read at offset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this error :

I/O error (torn page) detected during read at offset 0x0000024afe4000 in file for a user database. Using the first googled method, i set the database from master..sysdatabases from status 280 to status 24 but i still can't access it to run a DBCC CHECKDB.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a backup of the log tail, then restore from your most recent full backup and apply all log backups. In other words, apply your disaster recovery plan which you prepared for.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the SQL Server in single user mode from the command prompt.  Then flip the value to bring the database online then try running DBCC CHECKDB again.

Can you post any stack dump any information?